# Web Service returns different values in VB.NET vs SoapUI

Tags: vb.net, web-services, parsing, soap, fiddler

The IT department in my company has updated a web service by adding a new Boolean field to the return response. In my VB2010 project I have added the WSDL as a Web Service. I then run a query based on very basic inputs and get back three records. The new field returned is always False. When I run the same query in SoapUI I see that this field is True. In fact the query I am making has a filter to give me back all records where this field is True so am fairly positive the filter is working.

In VB.NET I am writing the records to a debug file immediately after the response comes back. All the other fields match except the new one. Being kind of new to the guts of web services I am uncertain what or where I can start troubleshooting.

The only troubleshooting I have done is to turn on Fiddler to intercept the response and looking at the XML the new field is True in the Fiddler app. So my guess is that the service in Visual Studio is not parsing it correctly.

Here is the response in SoapUI with ExcludeUpdate being the new field.

```
     <ns3:Machines>
        <ns3:procIdentifier>415782</ns3:procIdentifier>
        <ns3:OST>false</ns3:OST>
        <ns3:OLoaded>true</ns3:OLoaded>
        <ns3:ExcludeUpdate>true</ns3:ExcludeUpdate>
     </ns3:Machines>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out. Somehow the field in the service definition started with a lower case as in

```
    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property excludeUpdate() As Boolean
    End Property
```

but the actual XML written was upper case as in

```
 <ns3:Machines>
    <ns3:procIdentifier>415782</ns3:procIdentifier>
    <ns3:OST>false</ns3:OST>
    <ns3:OLoaded>true</ns3:OLoaded>
    <ns3:ExcludeUpdate>true</ns3:ExcludeUpdate>
 </ns3:Machines>
```

Once the XML output was changed to start with a lower case and the web service was updated in the Visual Studio project, everything started to work properly.